# What is the unit of Estimated Cost in the output of db2expln command?

Tags: db2, sql-execution-plan, db2-luw

Generated explain plan of a query in db2 11.5.
Received the following output:

Estimated Cost = 22.776293
Estimated Cardinality = 0.000000

What is the unit of Estimated Cost in the output of db2expln command?
Is it in seconds?

Comment: "timeron", an artificial unit - you can only compare them relatively, but they do not translate into seconds

Comment: Timerons just help you to compare one plan with another one. They are not specifically related to seconds or cost, or I/O, or RAM. A value of 22 should be considered "decently fast", depending on your needs, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here for the definition and explaination of costs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=information-explain-data-operators).

> A timeron is an invented relative unit of measurement. Timeron values
> are determined by the optimizer, based on internal values such as
> statistics that change as the database is used. As a result, the
> timeron values for an SQL or XQuery statement are not guaranteed to be
> the same every time an estimated cost in timerons is determined.

The above is for the **total costs**, but the explain should also show estimates for number of page I/Os, communication frames, CPU, etc.